# How does the ^J character ever show up in my registers?

Tags: vim, ascii

I've noticed some weird behavior in vim. If I this:

```
:redir @z
:pwd
:redir END
:reg
```

I will see something like this in my register --

```
^J^J/home/f41lurizer/workspace^J
```

The ^J is a single character. According to [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), it is a line feed character, with ascii code 10. Now, according to [this page on the vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Entering_special_characters), I can enter a character by entering C-v followed by it's ascii code. If I go into insert mode and type

```
C-v 010
```

I get this outputted:

```
^@
```

According to the wikipedia page, this is the null character with ascii code 0. I tried doing this with other characters, and C-v 013 for example will enter a ^M character, as expected.

I am getting this character in my registers when I redirect ex mode commands, and it's really messing me up, because its behavior when pasted is extremely irritating. I have two questions, I guess. The first is, why am I seeing this strange behavior with what seems to be a single ascii character? The second question is, assuming i have it in my register, how could I replace it with something that behaves sensibly, like ^M? I thought I could just split the string, using ^J as my delimiter, but if I can't even type the character, that's kind of hard to do.

EDIT: I've found something else that's weird. I looked up the vim digraphs help page, and [found this.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html) Notice anything weird about the LF and NU representations? They are both represented by ^@. I thought maybe it was a different implementation of the same thing, but the ascii codes of the two characters are the same (0) both times.

Edit 2: I've figured out how to split it. Apparently, I can use the null character as my delimiter. Still, I'd appreciate an explanation of some of the other strange behavior I've noticed.

Edit 3: It seems as though Vim uses the null character internally as a way to represent linebreaks before they are converted back into \n characters, because it uses c style strings internally. I guess this isn't such strange behavior afterall.

Comment: This is explained in `:help NL-used-for-Nul`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura I wouldn't say it's explained so much as just mentioned -- from the help doc "What is unusual is
that typing CTRL-V CTRL-J also inserts a <NL>, thus also searches for a <Nul> in the file." Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, though!

Comment: The explanation is the part you skipped: _<Nul> characters in the file are stored as <NL> in memory.  In the display they are shown as "^@".  The translation is done when reading and writing files._

Comment: I do not know if this has anything to do with your case but I am getting the same ^J character when I am creating folder names programmatically through python on my android device.